# Is this the right way to implement a hashmap?

Tags: java, hash-map

Is this the right way? Any comments on the hash functions? If asked a question like this in an interview, do I need to follow all OOP concepts(because I am using Java)? Like encapsulating the variables by writing getter and setter functions?

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;



public class HashMapY<K,V> {
    private static int capacity = 100;   
    private Map[] arr;
    private int size;

    public HashMapY () {
        arr = (Map[]) Array.newInstance(Map.class, capacity);
        size = 0;
    }

    public V get(Object key) {
        assert key!=null;
        int i = -1; 
        if (key instanceof String || key instanceof Character){
            i = hash(key.toString(), capacity) % capacity;
        }
        if (key instanceof Integer)
            i = hash(Integer.parseInt(key.toString()))%capacity;
        while (!key.equals(arr[i].k) && i < capacity)
            i = (i+1)%capacity;
        return arr[i]==null ? null : arr[i].v;
    }

    public int hash(String value, int maxValue) {
        long hash = doHash(value);
        return (int) Math.abs(hash % maxValue);
    }

    private int hash(int k) {
        k *= 357913941;
        k ^= k << 24;
        k += ~357913941;
        k ^= k >> 31;
        k ^= k << 31;
        return k;
    }

    private long doHash(String str) {
        long hash = 5381;

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + str.charAt(i);
        }

        return hash;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size==0;
    }



    public void put(K key, V value) {
        assert key != null;
        int i=-1;
        if (key instanceof String || key instanceof Character){
            i = hash(key.toString(), capacity) % capacity;
        }
        if (key instanceof Integer)
            i = hash(Integer.parseInt(key.toString()))%capacity;
        while (arr[i]!=null) {
            i = (i+1);
        }
        if(arr[i] == null) {
            size++;
        }
        arr[i] = new Map(key, value);
    }




    public V remove(Object key) {
        List<Map> pairs = new ArrayList<Map>();
        assert key!=null;
        int i = -1;
        if (key instanceof String || key instanceof Character)
            i = hash(key.toString(), capacity) % capacity;
        if (key instanceof Integer)
            i = hash(Integer.parseInt(key.toString()))%capacity;
        while (!arr[i].k.equals(key) && capacity > i){
            i = i + 1;
        }
        if (capacity >= i){
            Object temp = arr[i].v;
            while (arr[i]!= null && arr[i].k.equals(key)){

                pairs.add(arr[i]);
                arr[i] = null;
                size--;
            }
            for (Map m : pairs){
                this.put(m.k, m.v);
            }
            return (V) temp;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }



    class Map {
        K k;
        V v;

        public Map(K key, V val){
            k = key;
            v = val;
        }
    }



    public boolean containsKey(K key) {
        assert key!=null;
        int i = -1;
        if (key instanceof String || key instanceof Character)
            i = hash(key.toString(), capacity) % capacity;
        if (key instanceof Integer)
            i = hash(Integer.parseInt(key.toString()))%capacity;
        if (arr[i] == null) return false;
        while (i<capacity && !arr[i].k.equals(key)){
            i = i+1;
        }
        return i<capacity;
    }

    public Set<K> keySet() {
        Set<K> set = new HashSet<K>();
        for (Map m : arr){
            if (m != null){
                set.add(m.k);
            }
        }
        return set;
    }



}
```

Comment: @Ocelot20 Whitespace is subject to review, just like any other aspect of the code, so it should not be edited in the question. I've rolled back to Rev 1.

Answer (score 14):

No, this is not the correct way to implement a hash map in Java, and especially not to implement the `java.util.Map` interface.

- You aren't even explicitly implementing the `Map` interface.
- What is `(Map[]) Array.newInstance(Map.class, capacity)` supposed to be? I'd think a simple `new Map[capacity]` would be sufficient.
- You calculate your hashes yourself. However, every `Object` has a `hashCode()` method – use that instead.
- Because you shouldn't calculate the hash code yourself, you shouldn't do any special handling of `String` and `Character` or `Integer`.
- In your `get` method, what happens when the key is not one of your special classes? Not only will you be doing a linear search through your bins which breaks my expectations about the algorithmic complexity of a hash map, you'll also start at index `-1`, which will greet you with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.
- Should you be implementing `java.util.Map`, the `get` method should throw an explicit `NullPointerException` rather than an optional assertion error as you do not want to allow `null` keys.
- For some reason, the `hash` method is public. Furthermore, `hash` and `doHash` are not static although they don't access any object state.
- Many criticisms about `get` also apply to `put`.
- Your `remove` method sports this code: `arr[i].k.equals(key)`. That risks a null pointer exception when `arr[i]` is null. Instead: `arr[i] != null && key.equals(arr[i].k)`
- `remove` also has a loop that will only execute once or nonce:

  ```
  while (arr[i]!= null && arr[i].k.equals(key)){
      pairs.add(arr[i]);
      arr[i] = null;
      size--;
  }
  ```

  Note that you never modify `i`.
- In `remove`, it would be much simpler to look up the bin for that key, and then empty that bin rather. Consider putting your main `get` logic into a `private int getBin(Object key)`, which you could use both in `get`:

  ```
  int i = getBin(key);
  ... // assert i in range
  if (arr[i] != null) {
      return arr[i].v;
  }
  ```

  and `remove`:

  ```
  int i = getBin(key);
  ... // assert i in range
  if (arr[i] != null) {
      V value = arr[i].v;
      arr[i] = null;
      size--;
      return value;
  }
  ```
- The `Map` class would usually be named `Entry`. Note that the `java.util.Map` interface contains a nested interface [`java.util.Map.Entry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) which you'd also have to implement for compatibility.
- `containsKey` could be implemented using a `getBin` helper as

  ```
  int i = getBin(key);
  ... // assert i in range
  return arr[i] != null;
  ```
- Your hash map can only contain `100` elements. If it grows larger, you should reallocate the storage array. You are furthermore resolving hash collisions via “open addressing” (using the next free bucket). Alternatively, you could use linked lists in each bucket, which also simplifies growing the hash table.

Then, there are many style problems in your code.

- Consider changing a few `while`s to easier to read `for` loops.
- `i = i + 1` could be abbreviated to `i += 1`, but is most often written `i++`.
- Always use braces around the blocks of an `if`:

  ```
  if (key instanceof Integer) {
      i = hash(Integer.parseInt(key.toString())) % capacity;
  }
  ```
- Many of your casts could be prevented with the use of generics. In `remove`, you have

  ```
  Object temp = arr[i].v;
  ...
  return (V) temp;
  ```

  Instead:

  ```
  V temp = arr[i].v;
  ...
  return temp;
  ```

Regarding the question: “*do I need to follow all OOP concepts(because I am using Java)?*” – the answer is *yes*, but not because you are using Java. Instead, you'll want to write solid OOP code simply because your are writing object-oriented code, the language does not matter. Applying best practices is vastly preferable to producing shoddy, almost-working, bug-ridden code.

#### What now?

Your hash map implementation does not hold up to a code review. But that's not a problem.

- First, learn more about the topic: there is the [Wikipedia article on hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), there is also the source code for `java.util.HashMap` (e.g. [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/HashMap.java)). Compare what you've learned with your code, and try to understand your errors.
- Along the way, you'll probably also get better at actual Java programming.
- Then, try again. Start with a clean slate, and write another `HashMap` implementation. I'm sure you'll have improved by leaps and bounds. And please come back to have your new code reviewed :)